# Are these flip flop conversions correct

Tags: flipflop

Hi I am from computer science background and hence lack any solid foundation in electronics. I am trying to learn some flip flop conversions. Most of them are their online, however I did not found below two. So I made them myselves. But I need to know if I prepared the correct?

**SR flipflop to T flipflop**

[image]

**T flipflop to SR flipflop**

[image]

Are above conversions correct?

Comment: There are a good number of logic sims out there for free. Might want to check those out in case you have similar questions.

Comment: but are the above correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put - Yes, your schematics and tables are correct.

*Side note, you can find examples of these anywhere on the net as this is a typical study for undergrad elctrical engineering majors.